# Never in my life did I vs Never in my life had I

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, punctuation

Is saying "Never did I..." the same as saying "Never have I..." in the following examples?

Also, I'm not sure if I should add commas.

> Example 1: I never thought I would win a game against you.

1) Never in my life did I ever think that I would win a game against you

2) Never in my life had I ever thought that I would win a game against you

> Example 2: I had never thought that perfection existed until I saw her artwork.

3) Never in my life had I ever thought that perfection existed until I saw her artwork

4) Never in my life did I ever think that perfection existed until I saw her 
artwork.

Are all of them grammatically correct?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple issues in your problem that I can see. The most important one is that the tense in a normal alternative and its inversion should match; for example, *I've never ...* <--> *Never (in my life) have I*. Also note that all variants of time indicated by the tense for *Never in my life* are probably possible. (These are fine with me: *Never in my life do/did/will/would/have/had I ...*; depending on meaning and context, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to clear things up a bit, (1) and (3) match their normal alternatives. So, are they appropriate according to the context?

Comment: They sound fine to me, but keep in mind that I have only the sentences, so I have to assume a context that I think makes sense for each of them when I read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one issue with all of the sentences: after the initial "never", following with "ever" is redundant, unnecessary, and is at least bad style if not an error. It's like having "never ever" in a simple sentence.

Removing the "ever", in example 1 we are left with two possible sentences The first is:

> Never in my life did I think that I would win a game against you.

... which is just fine as it is.

The second is somewhat complex. The "had" makes past perfect tense, which suggests that there is another "thing" following, but still in the past, that is related to the statement; but that "thing" is missing. It would make sense if something follows, for example

> Never in my life had I thought that I would win a game against you, **but yesterday I did**.

But if you intend to contrast this "never" with the present, you should use present perfect:

> Never in my life *have* I thought that I would win a game against you, **but I seem to be in a winning position**.

Example 2 makes good use of past perfect;  "never had I thought...", and then "until I saw", still in the past.

Comment: Your answer's really helpful.Thanks a ton. If I intend to contrast "never" with the recent past, should I use "did I think"? Example: " I just beat you in that game. Never in my life did I think that I would win a game against you".

Comment: If you want to contrast with another time then a perfect tense is better. I think the close past in "I just beated you" has some "present feeling", so I would use present perfect, "have I thought", rather than past perfect. Past perfect is infrequent, and if you have doubts you probably shouldn't use it.